# August 2023 Writing Challenge: Introduce yourself

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by vote, here's the next challenge, proposed by me:

> A little autobiography never hurt anyone (or maybe that's part of your tragic backstory?). Tell us about yourself and what you're writing, in as much or as little detail as you feel comfortable.

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question or mention it in your answer.

Follow this question if you want to be notified instantly of any new answers.

You can also post and vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)